# Multivariable complex integration via the package cubature

Tags: r, numerical-methods, complex-numbers, numerical-integration

For my research, I am trying to implement the multidimensional inversion formula to compute density from a characteristic function

[image]

from the paper of [Sheppard (1991)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3532396). From my search, I know that the packages `pracma` and `elliptic` have functions to handle complex integrals but only up to 2 variables so it is not enough for me. There is also the package `CharFunToolR` that implements inversion formula, but limited to univariate function only. Another popular package that I am looking at is `cubature`, but the problem is that it can take a long time while the accuracy is not reliable. Plus, the package does not seem to handle complex numbers.

Here is an example that I used to test out using the multivariate normal characteristic function which I can validate the result because its density is well-known (in my research, I have a more complicated characteristic function).

```
p <- 6

mu <- c(-0.448, -0.48, -0.661, -0.325, -0.539, -0.297)

Sigma <- matrix(nrow = p, ncol = p, c(
   0.136, -0.013,  0.001, -0.009, -0.005, 0.004,
  -0.013,  0.123,  0.050,  0.002,  0.037, 0.040,
   0.001,  0.050,  0.095, -0.011,  0.056, 0.014,
  -0.009,  0.002, -0.011,  0.099, -0.005, 0.008, 
  -0.005,  0.037,  0.056, -0.005,  0.075, 0.003, 
   0.004,  0.040,  0.014,  0.008,  0.003, 0.102
))

x <- c(0.053, 0.523, -0.041, -0.589, -0.044, -0.066)
```

Using the function `dmvnorm()` in the package `mvtnorm`, I obtain

```
mvtnorm::dmvnorm(x, mu, as.matrix(Sigma))
[1] 0.01410531
```

Now, using the inversion formula approach

```
cf <- function(tee, x, mu, Sigma) {
  exp(-1i * crossprod(tee, x)) * exp(1i * crossprod(tee, mu) - 0.5 * t(tee) %*% Sigma %*% tee)
}

cub <- cubature::hcubature(
  f          = cf,
  lowerLimit = rep(-Inf, p),
  upperLimit = rep(Inf, p),
  tol        = 1e-4,
  maxEval    = 1000,
  x          = x,
  mu         = mu,
  Sigma      = Sigma
)

(2 * pi)^(-p) * cub$integral
[1] 0.07572407
```

which is quite off. What's worse is that if I increase `maxEval`, I get a completely different value

```
cub <- cubature::hcubature(
  f          = cf,
  lowerLimit = rep(-Inf, p),
  upperLimit = rep(Inf, p),
  tol        = 1e-4,
  maxEval    = 5000,
  x          = x,
  mu         = mu,
  Sigma      = Sigma
)

(2 * pi)^(-p) * cub$integral
[1] 0.2601113
```

It looks to me that with 1,000 or 5,000, the tolerance is not met, but if I don't specify `maxEval`, the function will take very long time, which is not practical to use. In addition, there is also a warning

```
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

Warning messages:
1: In cubature::hcubature(f = cf, lowerLimit = rep(-Inf,  ... :
  imaginary parts discarded in coercion
2: In cubature::hcubature(f = cf, lowerLimit = rep(-Inf,  ... :
  imaginary parts discarded in coercion
```

which makes me think that the function does not handle complex value very well (I looked at another thread using `integrate` and it said that we need to separate the real and imaginary part so `R` can understand). I also implemented a vectorized version of the characteristic function as instructed by the package's author to speed up the process, but I still get the same values as above. I think I need help making the code work properly with realistic running time and hopefully without the warning messages. Please help me if you can. If you are aware of any packages that can do the job, please let me know as well. Thank you so much.

Comment: Separate the real and the imaginary parts.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Do we have a mathematical formula to do that? Or it is something we need to do in R? Sorry, my knowledge of complex is pretty lacking.

Comment: You can use the Euler formula to decompose the `e^(ix)` into a real part and an imaginary part. But actually I'm afraid it's very hard or even impossible to numerically evaluate such integrals, because they are highly oscillatory.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is a hard problem as you said. Are you aware of any R packages that perform fast Fourier transformation for functions of more than 2 variables? Those of which I am aware, such as `fourierin` and `CharFunToolR` only allow 1 or 2 variables, which is pretty restrictive.

Comment: Plus, you are integrating (1) in 6 dimensions, and (2) over infinite domains. Both are exceptionally demanding for numerical integration routines. I think you will need more specialized libraries, not available for R, and/or more mathematical formulas. You should ask this on Stackexchange's 'Computational Science' Q&A site.